# Steam Media Library?

Tags: steam

I've noticed that some games on steam have links on their steam pages to media, for example soundtracks. Examining the shortcuts shows that they point to files residing on some of steam's servers. As example, **Dawn of War II** has the soundtrack on their page, pointing here: `http://media.steampowered.com/apps/15620/dow2_soundtrack.rar`. Another is **Greed: Black Borders**.

Does anyone know if there is any unpublished (or published) url which has some sort of a listing of all the ancillary media and files available for different games off of Steam?

Answer (score 1):

Just click on the [Videos](http://store.steampowered.com/freestuff/videos/) landmark.

Comment: Hmm, never saw that link before. Though I'm more looking for various soundtracks that I can stick on my Zune. DoWII and G:BB have some good music and I'm sure there are more good ones hiding in there. :) . I tried taking that URL `http://store.steampowered.com/freestuff/videos/` and just taking off the `videos/` on the end thinking maybe it would show everything, but then it only shows game demos. Thanks for the new info though.

Comment: Also tried replacing the `videos/` with `audios/` and `audio/`.

Comment: @eidylon I'm afraid the lack of landmarks for it means this information is not coherent enough to be structured -- in English, there aren't enough examples of that to justify an "`audios/`" section. I'd suggest just looking for the soundtracks of games you like.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there is an uber end all list for all games, but the media (videos, etc.) are listed right aside the game and demo for a given game.

Comment: Yeah; I was looking for something that did NOT involve going to *every* game's page to see if it had any free media or not... I don't think I have enough free time in my life to check them all!  ;)