# What is the "Media" section in Steam for?

Tags: steam

I have now purchased 2 games on Steam with soundtracks included.  Tiny and Big: Grandpa's Left Overs and Quantum Conundrum.  I am disappointed to find that the soundtracks are not accessibly from the Steam client, but instead by navigating through the game directories.

I thought the "Media" section of Steam would be where the soundtracks would be locatable.  I appear to be wrong, and currently to me this section seems to yield no purpose.

What exactly is this section for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is for downloading media off of the [Steam website](http://store.steampowered.com/).

Under any video on the steam website, there is a button labelled "Download".

[image: Download button below a video on the Steam website]

Clicking that button, will download the video (like a game) into your Steam client, but into that "Media" section.

[image: A Steam video in the Media section]

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7977/steam-media-library) may prove useful. The Steam Media area seems to do with videos and certain soundtracks. Dunno on the client, but I don't think the client and website are largely different.

Comment: Yep, it's for game trailers, movies and the like. For example the 'Meet the Engineer' and such from TF2 end up in here if you download the movie rather than stream it.